# Is it possible to create a dynamic SetEnv in an .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables

Currently I am trying to set an environment variable to point to a directory but I need it to be dynamic.

Currently I have the following

```
SetEnv WP_DIR /home/user101/website/public_html/www/app
```

Is it possible to make that WP_DIR variable get the `/home/user101/website/public_html/www` part dynamically?

Something like:

```
SetEnv WP_DIR ${CURRENT_PATH}/app
```

Please keep in mind that I am really new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetEnv` isn't equip to handle dynamic data as its value. But mod_rewrite can handle this for you. There isn't an ENV variable, to the best of my knowledge, which contains the current absolute path of the directory. But you can write something fancy to grab it:

```
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*?)/?\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=WP_DIR:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%2/app]
```

However setting ENV variables from .htaccess isn't so reliable since they can get prefixed by `REDIRECT_` if the URL gets rewritten. You'll have to keep an eye out for `REDIRECT_` prefixed variables from PHP.

If you have to do this kind of stuff in the first place, I think you're approaching your code wrong, PHP is well-equipped to process this kind of logic.

If you're trying to rewrite your requests to `index.php` and get around .htaccess's issue that it adds `REDIRECT_` in front of your variable names when you want to set ENV variables from .htaccess for PHP, I'd strongly suggest not using ENV variables in the first place. One approach is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]`. But I dislike this ugly approach since it uses the querystring. The best method I've found is to simply rewrite your requests to `index.php` then from PHP you'd read `strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?')` will contain the request the user requested without the query string. You'd still reference `$_GET[...]` for such parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also thank you for your suggestions I'll keep them in mind!

Comment: Is it possible to explain the rewrite condition and rule to me? If that is not a problem.

Comment: The RewriteCond is paired with the RewriteRule. When the RewriteCond refers to any $0 or $1 etc, it refers to the matches in the regexp in the RewriteRule. $0 refers to the entire match, thus in this case whatever RewriteRule is working on. The `#` in the RewriteCond is a separator character since URLs sent to the server will never contain a hash, this part stays with the browser. Thus we want to compare that with `REQUEST_URI`. On the right-hand side we match around the `#` so we have `%1` and `%2`. Finally we use `\1` which references our `%1` excluding what the two have in common from `%2`

Comment: I should add a note I borrowed the complex aspect of the logic from http://www.tacodewolff.nl/articles/htaccess and adjusted it to use `.*?` so it's less greedy so I could add `/?` to remove the tailing slash, then added `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` to get the absolute path of the web root.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PassEnv` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) to pass on env variable from system to Apache:

```
PassEnv CURRENT_PATH

SetEnv WP_DIR ${CURRENT_PATH}/app
```

Comment: I see a HOME variable when i do printenv.

Should I do:

`PassEnv HOME
 SetEnv WP_DIR ${HOME}/public_html/www/app
`

Comment: Yes that is how it should work. You can even pass any system environment variable.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I tried restarting the server but that didn't work as well.